# Capitalize "million" when using as a unit

Tags: technical-writing, scientific-publishing

When you write "1 Million", should it be "1 Million" or "1 million"?

I would assume capital based on the [symbol for mega being 'M'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would write "1 million" or "1M". When abbreviated, capitalization is necessary, but by itself, "million" is lowercase.

[capitalizemytitle.com](https://capitalizemytitle.com/ufaqs/are-million-billion-and-trillion-capitalized/#:%7E:text=So%2C%20million%2C%20billion%2C%20hundred,spelling%20rules%20of%20that%20class.) explains this:

> ...million, billion, hundred, thousand are NOT capitalized, and neither are the words “billionaire” or “millionaire” as they are considered to be professions, and they follow the spelling rules of that class.
>
> However, the first letter of million can be capitalized when abbreviated, as in “his net worth is well over $1,000,000MM” or “The stock market received an injection of $3,697,834Mil to keep it from collapsing”.